# How to construct a m x m correlation matrix

Tags: r, algorithm, function

I don't have a dataset, just need to create a m * m correlation matrix A, A = Aij. Just like deconstructing the function cor(df, method = "pearson").

Any idea. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. *"deconstructing the function cor"* What does that mean? Can you provide an example with sample data/expected output?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a valid m * m correlation matrix, you can simply use

```
n <- 100
m <- 5
x <- matrix(rnorm(n*m, 0, 1), nrow=n)
cor(x)
```

Another useful way is to use [Wishart Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) to generate a covariance matrix and then a correlation matrix, use

```
m <- 5
S <- toeplitz((m:1)/m) # you can design the structure
set.seed(11)
R <- rWishart(1, 20, S)[,,1]
cov2cor(R)
```